# Php if empty variable

Tags: php

So, I have following variables:

```
<?php
$multi_images = image($image, $rh_post_id);
?>
```

Then, I want to show something like this only if the variable is not empty.
I am not sure what the best way to do it.

```
<?php if ( empty($multi_images())) { ?>                         
    no images
<?php }else{ ?>
    there is an image
<?php } ?>
```

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you use `echo` instead of opening and clogin php tags.. or set the valur of variable in loop first and than display the value of variable

Comment: Are you calling a variable or a function?

Comment: yeah, i had few divs and didn't want to change all.

Comment: and i am calling a variable, like a image source (So, it will like numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd code it like so, with the assumption that $multi_images is an array of images.

```
<?php if ( isset($multi_images) && is_array($multi_images) && count($multi_images) > 0) : ?>                         
    no images
<?php else : ?>
    there is an image
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Make sense! =) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling a variable or a function?

```
 $multi_images;
```

or

```
multi_images();
```

Each one is different. If you want to validate a response from a function you'll use:

```
if (empty(image($image, $rh_post_id))){  ... }
```

on a variable:

```
if (empty($image)){ ... }
```

to check that the response is not empty. You'll want to use the exclamation mark `!`  so it'll be:

```
if (!empty($var)){ .. }
```

which will translate to

> if variable is not empty